# How to set databinding property to textblock in wpf usercontrol?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
 <TextBlock Margin="0,109,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold"
            FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF575757" RenderTransformOrigin="-3.611,3.696" ClipToBounds="True" Text="---------------------" Width="213"/>
```

This is my XAML textblock code which is part of usercontrol UI element.

How do i databinding to this?

when  i try to put

```
Text="{Binding ClickCount1, ElementName=myusercontrol, Mode=Default}
```

the XAML giving errors and design view become invisible.

pls help.

Comment: Does any `UserControl` exists with name `myusercontrol` ?

Comment: Yes . i have crated the usercontrol namely "myusercontrol"

Comment: What does this show  `Text="{Binding ElementName=myusercontrol, Mode=Default}` ?

Comment: In Simple words,  In C#, we set text for control, like Ctrl,Text  = "data";  like that how do i set the text for Textblock control...

Comment: what is `ClickCount1` in your binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

UserControl Example

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.myusercontrol"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="ClickCount1" Text="12" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Window Example using User Control with Binding

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:myusercontrol x:Name="MyUserControl" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl.ClickCount1, Path=Text}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you. and works fine. I couldnt make this as a answer due to low reputation count of my profile.